# Is the loop condition calculated each loop for "for" sentence in Java?

Tags: java, optimization, loops

This is my Java code:

```
List<Object> objects = new ArrayList();

// Assign values to objects
...

for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
    Object object = objects.get(i);
    ...
}
```

I have two questions:

1. Is `objects.size()` calculated only once before stating the loop, or is it calculated each loop?
2. If `objects.size()` is calculated each loop, then if other thread change it at the same time without multi-threads protection, the code may be crashed.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Answers:

1. `objects.size()` is *called* every loop (whether it is *calculated* depends on the ArrayList implementation, which you shouldn't care about)
2. Yes, another thread may change the list and this will affect your loop

Real answer:

You shouldn't have to care, and here's how you don't have to:

1. Use a [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html), which is thread-safe. If you iterate over it using an Iterator (as the foreach syntax uses internally), you'll iterate over the list *as it was when the iteration started*
2. Use the `foreach` syntax, which means you don't have to use an index etc - it's done for you:

```
for (Object object : objects) {
    // do something with each object 
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it is calculated each time.  If you have another thread altering the size of your objects list, the loop condition will keep changing.

Answer (score 2):

yes when you are using `objects.size()` inside the loop condition it calculates every time. better way is to keep it in a variable before going into loop;
like int

```
 limit=objects.size(); 
 for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    Object object = objects.get(i);
 ...
 }
```

If you have another thread it may change it but using the above option it will not affect or crash you programm.

Comment: This, of course supposes that the object does not change size, which is totally missing the second question

Comment: for this you can use the option provided by Bohemian

Answer (score 1):

yes , it will calculate each time

if you look into for loop statement, in the first statement it will set counter initial value
then it will check for maximum value then it will execute for loop body then after it will increase value of counter and then again check for maximum value. every time to check maximum value it will call size method.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Is objects.size() calculated only once before stating the loop, or is it calculated each loop?

Each time.

> 1. If objects.size() is calculated each loop, then if other thread change it at the same time without multi-threads protection, the code may be crashed.

Yes. Or at least, you may get a `ConcurrentModificationException`, and not have any reasonable way to deal with it.

Please note that this could happen even if you cached `objects.size()`, except now the `.get()` will fail instead because you are trying to get an index that no longer exists. `objects.size()` changes because something is removed from, or added to, the container.

Don't modify collections while you are iterating over them.

Comment: You probably won't get a `ConcurrentModificationException` with most classes, because you haven't opened an `Iterator`. CME usually only comes about when you open an Iterator, then modify the collection (except by methods provided by the Iterator), and then try to use that same Iterator again. So for instance, if this `ArrayList` had been wrapped in a `Collections.synchronizedList`, this code would work fine -- except that you'd have a race condition whereby you could end up with an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Er, yes. Sorry, I'm accustomed to seeing people iterate in modern ways, what with usually working in Python :)

Comment: @KarlKnectel Java has those modern ways, too! :) `for (Object obj : objects) { ... }` That's syntactic sugar for opening and using an `Iterator`, so that can definitely throw CME.

Comment: I added a new item in array list in for each loop & it didn't crash because of CME. Isn't for each using iterator internally?

Answer (score 1):

Notionally the objects.size() could be evaluated on each loop. However, as the method is short it can be inlined and cached as its not a volatile variable. i.e. another thread could change it but there is no guarantee that if it did you would see the change.

A short way to save the size is to use the follow.

```
for (int i = 0, size = objects.size(); i < size; i++) {
    Object object = objects.get(i);
...
}
```

However if you are concerned that another thread could change the size, this approach only protects you if an object is added.  If an object is removed you can still get an exception when you attempt to access the value which is now beyond the end of the list.

Using a CopyOnWriteArrayList avoids these issues (provided you use an Iterator) but makes writes more expensive.